# Valgrind reports memory leak though there isn't one [c]

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

My code looks like :

```
void kernel_version(char * kernel_str)
{
    FILE * fp       = fopen(log, "a");
    FILE * pipe     = popen("uname -r", "r");

    if(fp && pipe)
    {
        //
    }

    pclose(pipe);
    pclose(fp);
}
```

Leaks usually occur when memory is being allocated dynamically. However, I am not dynamically allocating the memory anywhere in my code.
I am unable to point out the leak.

Comment: Calling pclose on fp in kernel_version seems dubious ...

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder Yes, I pointed it out already. I'm sure that's where things are going wrong.

Comment: Where does [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) say that the leak is?  Why aren't you showing us its output — or the relevant subsection of the output?  It is futile making us guess when you've been told.  And just because the code you wrote doesn't use dynamic memory allocation doesn't mean that the functions you call (which you didn't write) are not doing dynamic memory allocation.  Lots of functions do dynamic memory allocation.  File stream operations often do dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: pawan is wright... changing pclose to fclose worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the last line be `fclose(fp)`?

I think that's where things are going wrong.

Change `pclose(fp)` to `fclose(fp)`.

```
fopen() -> fclose()

popen() -> pclose()
```